# Parse XML from VBA not working

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I am trying to parse xml file using excel vba. This is how my xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Environment>
    <Variable>
        <Name></Name>
        <Caption>T1</Caption>
        <Type>TEXT</Type>
        <Value>V1</Value>
        <Description></Description>
    </Variable>
        <Variable>
        <Name></Name>
        <Caption>T2</Caption>
        <Type>TEXT</Type>
        <Value>V2</Value>
        <Description></Description>
    </Variable>
        <Variable>
        <Name></Name>
        <Caption>T3</Caption>
        <Type>TEXT</Type>
        <Value>V3</Value>
        <Description></Description>
    </Variable> <Variable>
        <Name></Name>
        <Caption>T4</Caption>
        <Type>TEXT</Type>
        <Value>V4</Value>
        <Description></Description>
    </Variable> <Variable>
        <Name></Name>
        <Caption>T5</Caption>
        <Type>TEXT</Type>
        <Value>V5</Value>
        <Description></Description>
    </Variable>
    </Variable> <Variable>
        <Name></Name>
        <Caption>T6</Caption>
        <Type>TEXT</Type>
        <Value>V6</Value>
        <Description></Description>
    </Variable>
</Environment>
```

And here is my code to parse it:

```
Public Function ll()
Dim doc As DOMDocument60
Set doc = New DOMDocument60
doc.Load "E:\web\cc.xml"
Dim Variables As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim variable As IXMLDOMNode
Set Variables = doc.SelectNodes("/Environment/Variable")
For Each variable In Variables
    Debug.Print variable.SelectNodes("Caption").Item(0).Text
    Debug.Print variable.SelectNodes("Type").Item(0).Text
Next
End Function
```

But I am not able to get this successfully run. I am using Excel 2013 and I have referenced to Microsoft XML 6.0. But nothing happens on execution. I tried to catch error with an on error statement, but it returns error number 0. Can anybody tel what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: The XML is not well formed. There is an `</Variable>` to much before the last `Variable` element.

Comment: Agree with @AxelRichter. VTC

Comment: A good way to investigate cases like this is to single-step through the code (F8 in the VBA editor).  Then you can interact with the objects in the immediate window (e.g. `debug.print Variables.Count` will tell you how many nodes your `SelectNodes` returned) and see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A XML parser can only work if the XML is well formed. If not, the `oXMLDOMDocument.load` method fails.

To check this, you could use `oXMLDOMDocument.parseError` like this:

```
Public Function ll()

 Dim oDoc As Object
 Set oDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
 oDoc.Load "E:\web\cc.xml"

 Dim oErr As Object

 If oDoc.parseError.ErrorCode <> 0 Then
  Set oErr = oDoc.parseError
  Debug.Print oErr.reason
 End If

 Dim oVariables As Object
 Dim oVariable As Object
 Set oVariables = oDoc.SelectNodes("/Environment/Variable")
 For Each oVariable In oVariables
  Debug.Print oVariable.SelectNodes("Caption").Item(0).Text
  Debug.Print oVariable.SelectNodes("Type").Item(0).Text
 Next

End Function
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx