# Is there any function similar to offset that can be applied to collections in VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, function, csv

As a basic user of VBA, I would like to know whether there is something similar to the offset function that can be applied to the elements of a collection. Does it exist or does it need to be created as a user-defined function? I want to start from something similar to the code in the accepted answer (thank you again, Tim) to the following question [Updating an .xml document according to a .csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703113/updating-an-xml-document-according-to-a-csv-file).
For the sake of simplicity, let suppose that I have to perform a find in a .csv file, and I'll use the function below, which will be a collection object.

```
Sub editxml()
    
    Dim Obj As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim xmlpath As String
    Dim Node As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim Nm As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim thing As Object, q As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim matches As Collection

    Set Obj = New DOMDocument
    Obj.async = False
    Obj.validateOnParse = False
    
    xmlpath = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\ppp.xml"
    Obj.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ns0='http://update.DocumentTypes.Schema.ppp.Xml'"
    
    If Obj.Load(xmlpath) = True Then
        MsgBox "File XML uploaded"
    Else
        MsgBox "File XML not uploaded"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'open the CSV file
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\mycopy.csv")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    
    Set Node = Obj.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("AA/BB/CC/DD")
    
    For Each Nm In Node
        Set thing = Nm.SelectSingleNode("thing")
        Set q = Nm.SelectSingleNode("qt")
        
        'moved the Find logic to a standalone function
        Set matches = FindAll(ws.Range("AR:AR"), thing.Text)
        
        'did we get any matches in the range?
        If matches.Count > 0 Then
            'This section of the code should perform some computations according to the value of a particular cell in a different column, so basically it should offset the element of the collection. 
            q.Text = "do somewhat else"
        End If
    Next
        
    Obj.Save xmlpath
    
End Sub

'find all matching cells in a range and return them in a Collection
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range, addr As String
    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address() 'store first cell found
    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do 'exit if we've looped back to first cell
    Loop
    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```

I know that the offset function can be applied to range object in VBA. If I had to work with ranges, I would do something like that in the missing section of my code, but this obviously doesn't work. I'd like to keep the object matches as a collection, since it's more flexible for my purposes.

```
        If matches.Count > 0 Then
            'This section of the code should perform some computations according to the value of a particular cell in a different column, so basically it should offset the element of the collection. 
            q.Text = matches.offset(0,-3).value*matches.offset(0,-6)
        End If
    Next
```

Update: I'd like to perform some computations between the values in the cells of my .csv file. For every element in the collection, i.e the address, let say that the first element of matches is AR2, I have to do something like D2*S2. Basically, I have to start from the result of the function and 'move' by column, remaining on the same row. This was the meaning of offset.

Comment: It makes no sense for `Offset` to work with collection objects themselves because it only makes sense for ranges. Your collection contains `Range`s as elements, apparently you wanted to loop over all these `Range`s and apply `Offset` to each?

Comment: You are storing range addresses in your collection. With `offset`, you probably mean offset from that address?

Comment: @FunThomas `f` is a `Range`.

Comment: @Gserg: You're right, misread the code. Remains the question what the OP means with "offset"

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Can you supply sample data and expected outcome? Offset has row and column which you don't have with a collection. You would in essence be accessing an item by +|- n from current index (thinking literally and not really knowing what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: I updated my question, thank you for replying.

Comment: Still not clear what you want accomplishing. `matches.offset(0,-3).value*matches.offset(0,-6)` does not make any sense, but `matches(1).offset(0,-3).value * matches(1).offset(0,-6).value` makes some sense, since the collection elements are ranges. But this approach makes sense, too only if you previously check what range/cell is inside the first collection element. Which may work but why to proceed in this way having the range still available...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the collection is a collection of ranges you would have to loop through them:

```
If matches.Count > 0 Then
    Dim match As Range
    For Each match in matches
        q.Text = match.Offset(0, -3).Value * match.Offset(0, -6).Value
    Next match
End If
```

NOTE: `q.Text` would only hold the last value in the collection. This works if you only have one match but I'm not sure what you want to do when there are multiple matches.

Comment: Thank you, it was much simpler than I expected.